# Shadow squares on meshes

Tags: lighting, blender, webgl, shadows, three.js

[image: Ribbed shadows on object]

I had created project on r3f (React THREE Fiber), and after "blocking" when I decided to add high resolution models, I noticed this shadow issue.

Help me to understand, how can I fix the shadow stairs on my models?

I had tried some of the variants, I had exported model with and without smooth shading and auto-smoothing on normals.

So I decided to look on **Directional light** or **Point light** and tried to handle them.
But it gave me nothing like increasing shadow map size.

But one thing I knew, the light is the reason why my models show this buf with the shadows.

[On this site I have a good results, without shadow stairs etc.](https://threejs.org/editor/)

When we have  light angle of 90° relative to the model's surface, everything looks fine. But if we have a sharper angle, we will have shadow stairs.